# Excel export getting error : A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a method that creates an Excel file from my report,
If in my columns I have some Arabic characters like " ُ", " َ" I get this error "A generic error occurred in GDI+" but I need to show this character, and can not remove those. So if you had this problem please help me.
I search for this problem and add headers below, but the problem was not resolved in `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;  HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());`

```
            using( var wb = new XLWorkbook() )
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                using( var myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream() )
                {
                    var maxRowsPerSheet = Server.GetConfig("MaxRow");
                    if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxRowsPerSheet) && int.TryParse(maxRow, out int max) )
                    {
                        var tables = SplitTable(table, max);
                        foreach( var tbl in tables )
                        {
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(tbl, "sheet" + (tables.IndexOf(tbl) + 1));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wb.Worksheets.Add(table, "sheet1");
                    }
                    wb.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                    myMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                }

            }
    }`
```

Comment: HTTP uses HTML characters.  You need to encode any special characters.  Use : string encode = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(excel).  Then add the string to the context (body) of the request.  Also the data you are putting into the body is a string (not "application/vnd.ms-excel").

Comment: Show (or look yourself) the content of the excel string.I highly doubt it contains what you expect.